# Rails/devise intermittent session issues between log out, log in and expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I am preparing my first Rails online deployment and I'm sooo close to a limited, closed release to trial with users.

I *think* my question is, how do I force and guarantee the local user session data is cleared from the browser at the appropriate times?

The issue I have is an intermittent (looks like permanent and fatal app failure, but it's not) error thrown when someone goes to sign in or sign up after a period of idle time (ie, after session timeout): "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Another user on a different device does not get this error. The app signs in and operates for them as intended.

The log shows (superfluous info removed):

```
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2021-06-27 13:37:25 +1000
D, SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."first_name" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "b2186826-a1f7-48ca-9d04-825b3d8b3e4c"], ["LIMIT", 1]]   
F, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "session.tenant_id"
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."first_name" ASC LIMIT $2):
F, activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:622:in `exec_prepared'
activerecord (5.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:622:in `block (2 levels) in exec_cache'
activesupport (5.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
.
.
.
```

The app is multi-tenanted and uses two Postgres session variables - one for user access level (the Postgres RLS role to apply: login, tenant or app admin) and one for tenant ID (this is where the session:tenant_id error comes from, above). These are set accordingly each time a controller action is called, to maintain integrity with the RLS in the database.

I also have devise timeoutable set to 60 minutes and am employing the method at the following link to kick people out and back to the login after this delay (I'm not yet convinced the specified delay is being honoured, but that's another story) - Link: https://medium.com/code/user-session-inactivity-timeout-with-rails-and-devise-7269ac3a8213

On the app server, no amount of puma restart or server restart will recover the server. The error only shows on a particular device that has recently timed out (and sometimes for signed out too). If another user signs in from another device, they do not get the failure and the server works as expected for them. If I clear the browser cache and cookies on the device that is failing, it resumes operating for them.

From what I have read, Devise automatically resets the session on the browser at sign in and sign out??? The local session data is simply search parameters. I threw a basic search onto a couple of list views...perhaps if I instead use Datatables I can do away with storing session data...perhaps this would avoid the issues I am having?

Secondary to this, and as a result of this intermittent behaviour, I am considering a trial of token authentication instead. See https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've sort of fixed this issue...I also now can see what in fact has been going on...

It seems the postgres parameters/variables being used for the Row Level Security were being lost at about the five minute mark of no activity, causing the crash error message. This must have been a result of devise logging the user out after about 5 minutes of inactivity (not configured for this at all!)

The fix was to place the following into the database.yml file, under the host and port settings in the default section:

```
  variables:
    session.access_level: "guest"
    session.tenant_id: ""
```

Now what I get is a graceful logout and return to the sign in form. The issue here is that it does not matter what the devise timeoutable setting is - whether it is removed (from user model and devise initializer) or set to 60 minutes, this has not effect...no matter what the user was doing, inactivity of about 5 minutes results in them being logged out. I'd much rather extend this to about 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up...it appears it was devise rememberable! This was overriding timeoutable and causing the constant logouts.